# How to find all the gsp pages in a whole application which are authorized for a particular user role in grails?

Tags: grails

I have to find all the view names (.gsp names) which are authorized for a particular role eg `Global_Admin`. This does not include any database operation and should be identified from controller method only.

User role is mentioned in controller class just above the method declaration in the format given below. An example of one controller:

```
class JobController {

    @Secured(["hasAnyRole('Global_Admin')"])
    def jobsList(){
        // Business logic here

        render(view:"jobsList")
    }
}
```

So, I need to search all the controller classes inside the application and find the view name for each method that is authorized to `Global_Admin`. I should display this list in a new GSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. I'm providing a basic code assuming the annotations are present over the actions or methods.

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class MyController {

   def grailsApplication

   def test() {
        List<String> gspsWithAnnotation = []

        // Iterate each controller class
        grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { controller ->
            // Iterate each action of the controller
            controller.getClazz().methods.each { method ->
                // See if action has Secured annotation
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Secured)) {
                    List<String> value = method.getAnnotation(Secured).value()
                    // See if annotation value is "Global_Admin"
                    if (value.any { it.contains("Global_Admin")}) {
                        // Then put that action name to the list
                        gspsWithAnnotation << method.name
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        println "All GSPs with annotation: $gspsWithAnnotation"
        [gspsWithAnnotation: gspsWithAnnotation]
    }
}
```

Just verify the package of the `Secured` annotation. Of course this code checks the `Secured` annotation over the action, you can tweak it to see the annotation over the controller class also.